# What exactly IUpdate::BundledUpdates retrieves?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop-application, windows-update, wmic

When we try to retrieve the Windows Update Information with WUA API, the following is the process I have followed. But I am bit confused with IUpdate::BundledUpdates property.

1. Create an IUpdateSearcher
2. Search based on a search criteria. I provided search criteria as "IsHidden=1 or IsInstalled=1"
3. You will have a IUpdateCollection as result of search.
4. Using get_Item in IUpdateCollection, I retrieved each update (IUpdate) and printed the required values (KB numbers in my case).
5. But again in IUpdate, you have a BundledUpdate property that gives IUpdateCollection with get_BundledUpdates() method. When I iterated over the results of BundledUpdates, I have got no results.

Am I missing something in retrieving bundled updates? (OR) does the criteria I specified includes Bundled Updates as part of first result set of IUpdateCollection?

Also in MSDN, examples are lacking for each interface in WUA API, Could someone provide any resources that explains clearly what each interface in WUA API does?

Added full source code of C++ console Application:

```
#include <wuapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <wuerror.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUpdateSession* iUpdate;
    IUpdateSearcher* searcher;
    ISearchResult* results;
    BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=1 or IsHidden=1 or IsPresent=1");

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&iUpdate);
    hr = iUpdate->CreateUpdateSearcher(&searcher);

    wcout << L"Searching for updates ..."<<endl;
    hr = searcher->Search(criteria, &results);
    SysFreeString(criteria);

    switch(hr)
    {
    case S_OK:
        wcout<<L"List of applicable items on the machine:"<<endl;
        break;
    case WU_E_LEGACYSERVER:
        wcout<<L"No server selection enabled"<<endl;
        return 0;
    case WU_E_INVALID_CRITERIA:
        wcout<<L"Invalid search criteria"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IUpdateCollection * updateList;
    IUpdate *updateItem;
    LONG updateSize;
    BSTR updateName;

    results->get_Updates(&updateList);
    updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);

    if (updateSize == 0)
    {
        wcout << L"No updates found"<<endl;
    }

    for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
    {
        IStringCollection *KBCollection;
        LONG KBCount;
        updateList->get_Item(i, &updateItem);
        updateItem->get_KBArticleIDs(&KBCollection);
        KBCollection->get_Count(&KBCount);
        for(int k=0;k<KBCount;k++)
        {
            BSTR KBValue;
            KBCollection->get_Item(k,&KBValue);
            wcout << L"KB" << KBValue << endl;
        }

        //Retrieve the bundled updates
        IUpdateCollection *updtCollection;
        updateItem->get_BundledUpdates(&updtCollection);
        LONG updtBundledCount;
        updtCollection->get_Count(&updtBundledCount);
        for(LONG j=0;j<updtBundledCount;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Bundled KBs" <<endl;
            IUpdate *bundledUpdateItem;
            updtCollection->get_Item(j,&bundledUpdateItem);
            bundledUpdateItem->get_KBArticleIDs(&KBID);
            if(KBID != NULL)
            {
                LONG KBCount;
                BSTR KBIDValue;

                KBID->get_Count(&KBCount);
                for(LONG j=0;j<KBCount;j++)
                {

                    wcout << "KB" <<(KBIDValue) << endl;
                    temp.setKBID(KBIDValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    wcout << L"Total KB Count : " << updateSize << endl;
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyone please respond to my queries?

Comment: Maybe no one knows. You shouldn't expect an immediate answer online either.

Comment: Can you include the source code which you are using to retrieve the BundledUpdates?

Comment: @RRUZ I edited the question and have added the source code.

Comment: @RRUZ Could you please look into the source code I have added?

Comment: @HareeshSarma in order to get help please post a full `C++` console app.

Comment: @RRUZ I have added the complete source code as per you request. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fix your code in order to retrieve the Bundled Updates.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wuapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <wuerror.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUpdateSession* iUpdate;
    IUpdateSearcher* searcher;
    ISearchResult* results;
    BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=1 or IsHidden=1 or IsPresent=1");

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&iUpdate);
    hr = iUpdate->CreateUpdateSearcher(&searcher);

    wcout << L"Searching for updates ..."<<endl;
    hr = searcher->Search(criteria, &results); 
    SysFreeString(criteria);

    switch(hr)
    {
    case S_OK:
        wcout<<L"List of applicable items on the machine:"<<endl;
        break;
    case WU_E_LEGACYSERVER:
        wcout<<L"No server selection enabled"<<endl;
        return 0;
    case WU_E_INVALID_CRITERIA:
        wcout<<L"Invalid search criteria"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IUpdateCollection *updateList;
    IUpdate *updateItem;
    LONG updateSize;
    BSTR updateName;

    results->get_Updates(&updateList);
    updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);

    if (updateSize == 0)
    {
        wcout << L"No updates found"<<endl;
    }

    for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
    {
        IStringCollection *KBCollection;
        LONG KBCount;
        updateList->get_Item(i,&updateItem);
        updateItem->get_Title(&updateName);
        wcout<<i+1<<" - "<<updateName<<endl;

        IUpdateCollection *updtCollection;
        LONG updtBundledCount;        
        //Retrieve the bundled updates
        updateItem->get_BundledUpdates(&updtCollection);
        hr = updtCollection->get_Count(&updtBundledCount);
        if ((updtBundledCount>0) && (hr ==S_OK))
        {
            wcout << L"Bundled Updates " <<(updtBundledCount) << endl;
            for(LONG j=0;j<updtBundledCount;j++)
            {
                IUpdate *bundledUpdateItem;
                BSTR bundledName;
                updtCollection->get_Item(j,&bundledUpdateItem);   
                bundledUpdateItem->get_Title(&bundledName);
                wcout<<L"    "<<j+1<<" - "<<bundledName<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    wcin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. My query was, When I was trying to retrieve the KB Number in the bundled update, I am not able to get any values, Is it because each bundled update is installed on the machine and when I try to query the total list of updates, It also includes the bundled updates? In the code I posted earlier, the place where I was retrieving the KB numbers include everything?

Comment: Also I have one more query regarding WUA -- what coding measures need to be taken care so that WUA API works properly across all windows. The code which you have given above is not working properly in all OS. I tried in Vista and XP where in Vista no data was returned and in XP it gave less results than WMIC QFE GET. Could you please answer this also?

Comment: Could you please answer my queries?